# Gradle function to define custom maven repository?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I end up having to define my maven repository all over the place in my `build.gradle` files. The definition can often be very cumbersome:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()

    maven {
        url "https://mymavenurl/releases"
        credentials(Credentials) {
            username USERNAME
            password PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
```

Notice above how gradle offers a nice way of defining commonly used maven repositories (i.e. `jcenter()`). I'd like a way in a plugin or in a parent gradle script to define the repository in a function, or statically, and then just call it inside the `repositories` block: `myMavenRepo()`.

My knowledge of groovy is lacking, so I don't quite have the understanding I need to parse the groovy sources that I'm seeing to find a nice way to do this. How would I do this?

I'm aware that in a parent gradle file, I could use `allProjects` or `subProjects`. I don't want to add these maven repositories to all modules, but instead only specific ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
repositories.ext.myRepo = {
    repositories.maven {
        url "https://mymavenurl/releases"
        credentials() {
            username USERNAME
            password PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to call:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    myRepo()
}
```

The same can be accomplished for buildscript repositories:

```
buildscript.repositories.ext.myRepo = {
    buildscript.repositories.maven {
        url "https://mymavenurl/releases"
        credentials() {
            username USERNAME
            password PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To me it only works for repositories but not for buildscript.repositories

Comment: this works: project.buildscript.repositories.ext.mavenMyPluginsRelease = {
    project.buildscript.repositories.maven {...

Answer (score 2):

If you use these repository in all your projects, you can define them in an [initialization script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html). Just create a file `$HOME/.gradle/init.gradle` which contains

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        maven {
            url "https://mymavenurl/releases"
            credentials(Credentials) {
                username USERNAME
                password PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I should have specified. I don't want to add it to all projects.