# How to add a method to every `repositories` block, or every RepositoryHandler?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

A large project with many developers and gradle projects uses a private maven repository for plugins, dependencies, and publication.

I would like to define a `privateMaven()` method, just like the built-in `jcenter()`, `mavenCentral()`, and `google()` methods. Currently we write a `maven` block anywhere we need to use the repository - `repositories`, `publishing.repositories`, `pluginManagement.repositories`, ...

```
repositories {
  maven {
    url "..."
    credentials { ... }
  }
}
```

which I would rather be

```
repositories {
  private()
}
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40390270/555631) explains how to extend `repositories` and `buildscript.repositories` but it doesn't work for `publishing.repositories` because `publishing` is provided by a plugin and doesn't work for `pluginManagement.repositories`. Also I would also have to enumerate every repositories configuration and developers can't use `privateMaven()` in any block we don't extend.

Is there a way for an init script to add a method to every `repositories` block, or every RepositoryHandler?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the maven-publish plugin, you can define an extension like so:

private.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing.repositories.ext.privateRepo = {
    publishing.repositories.maven {
        url "https://artifactory.website.com/private-repo"
        credentials {...}
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
apply from: 'private.gradle' // or you can just include the script in here

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {...}
        repositories {
            privateRepo()
        }
    }
}
```

You can also create a plugin if you'd like to distribute the script, the usage would remain exactly the same.
https://guides.gradle.org/implementing-gradle-plugins/

PrivatePlugin.groovy

```
class PrivatePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        // check if the publishing extension exists first
        final publishing = project.extensions.findByType(PublishingExtension.class)
        if (publishing != null) {
            publishing.repositories.ext.privateRepo = {
                publishing.repositories.maven {
                    url "https://artifactory.website.com/private-repo"
                    credentials {...}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just be sure that if you distribute it as a plugin that you don't ship it with the credentials hardcoded.

Comment: I've figured out how to add extensions to the dsl but I don't want to enumerate everywhere the `repositories` can appear. dependencies, plugins, publish plugins...

Answer (score 1):

My goal is that *any* repositories block can use `privateMaven`. I don't want to explicitly extend `publishing.repositories.ext`, `repositories.ext`, `buildscript.repositories.ext`. In addition to being tedious, if I miss one `repositories` or gradle adds a new `repositories` then `privateMaven` will not be available.

One solution which is close, but not perfect, was to create an extension on with a method that takes a reference to RepositoryHandler.

Any repository block and now use the extension as so

```
repositories {
  custom.privateMaven(it)
}
```

```
beforeSettings {
  extensions.create("custom", PrivateMavenExtension::class)
}
     
allprojects {
  extensions.create("custom", PrivateMavenExtension::class)
}

open class PrivateMavenExtension {
  fun privateMaven(handler: RepositoryHandler): MavenArtifactRepository {
    return handler.maven {
      // implementation
    }
  }
}
```

One major hurdle I haven't solved is that classes defined in an init.d script cannot be loaded in build.gradle. If `PrivateMavenExtensions` is defined in an init.d script I can't reference the extension in a type-safe way from a build.gradle.kts because `the<PrivateMavenExtension>()` cannot be resolved.